# Nginx server edit to allow iframe from any site

Tags: django, nginx

I've done a `curl -I www.site.com` and this is the result

```
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Server: nginx
Date: Mon, 21 Sep 2015 13:16:11 GMT
Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8
Content-Length: 103555
Connection: keep-alive
Vary: Accept-Encoding
Vary: Cookie
X-Frame-Options: SAMEORIGIN
Set-Cookie: csrftoken=hkixBLlqGGXlt1fGrbfBM3aF3G1Cpxxp; expires=Mon,    19-Sep-2016                                                                                         13:16:11 GMT; Max-Age=31449600; Path=/
```

I need to edit the server for `X-Frame-Options:` to allow all. This is delicate and as such I did not go around testing without being sure. Will appreciate some guidance on this.

Comment: What makes you think any special Apache configuration is needed here?

Comment: @DanielRoseman editions made after more research

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There was the clickjacking prevention in the middleware once I removed that it worked perfectly.

```
MIDDLEWARE_CLASSES = (
    #'django.middleware.cache.UpdateCacheMiddleware',
    #'django.middleware.gzip.GZipMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
    #'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.redirects.middleware.RedirectFallbackMiddleware',
    #'django.middleware.cache.FetchFromCacheMiddleware',
    'minidetector.Middleware',
    'mobileesp.middleware.MobileDetectionMiddleware',
    #'django_mobileesp.middleware.UserAgentDetectionMiddleware',
)
```